# Using a Segment Variable to display all products with the same title in a Playa field

Tags: ee2, playa

I've created a segment variable for brands that shows in the URL. I want to write an {if} statement that looks at the URL segment for brand and then brings back the products that match the playa field for brand. (ie. If the URL segment says BEAM I want to show all BEAM products that have been selected from the Playa filed). How do I go about doing this? Any suggestions?

Here's a very basic example. This doesn't include the code to only show products with the same name as {segment_6}. Any suggestions? I hope this helps.

```
<!--I only want to show the code below if segment_6 has something-->
{if segment_6 != ""}  
    {exp:store:search channel="products"}
        {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}

                <!--I want all of this code to display the products that match segment_6 with the Playa field brand selected in an entry-->
                {exp:playa:children field="brand"}
                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                {/exp:playa:children}

                <!--this should also display based on the brand in the playa field above-->                                                     
                {product_description}
            {product_image}                                         

        {/exp:store:product}        
    {/exp:store:search}
{/if}
```

[image: The URL including segment_6. Segment_4 and Segment_5 are comparing prices]

Comment: Please add more context to your question so we can better understand what your trying to accomplish. Post sample code too.

Comment: I've updated the questions. I hope this helps. Thanks for chiming in. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more context for the related channel associated with playa field `brand`? Does that channel have categories? How are all the BEAM products setup within that channel? Are they all related to a category BEAM?

Comment: The playa field is just a name (ie. Beam, Electrolux, Dyson, etc.). Each product is put into a category (ie. Portable, Canister, etc.). Each product is also assigned a brand (ie. the playa field with the brand name). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark as I'm still confused on how you have everything configured.

You could just pass the `{entry_id}` in the `{exp:playa:children}` playa tag and that would give you all related products that that entry created:

```
{exp:playa:children entry_id="{entry_id}" field="brand"}
     {title}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Comment: Sadly... That won't work in this case. I need to have an {if} statement that looks at the playa field (brands) for the products and then looks at the URL. If in segment_6 it says "Beam" it pulls all products that have the "Beam" brand selected from the Playa field. I hope that made sense. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Your question is trivial at this point. You'll need to add __way__ more details to your question on the specifics of the channel setup and how the relationships are created. It almost seems to me that you're using playa as a categories alternative. And if that's the case, maybe the playa `{exp:playa:sibilings}` tag might work.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry this is so frustrating. I've added some comments to the code and added a screenshot of the URL. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Is what's in segment 6 the url_title of the brand entry in the brands channel?

Comment: Hi Jean. Thank you for the response. Segment_6 is just a fake URL. The name that appears in segment_6 is the same name that is in the brands channel. Segment_6 isn't being added by the channel though. I'm just creating a link that includes this segment. I really hope that made sense. Is there a way to display segment_6 from the channel and then call on products that have a specific product that is tagged from the Playa field? Again... Thank you for your time.

Comment: So you have a playa field in the brands channel field group and not in the products channel field group? Am I understanding that correctly? Or is it the other way around (which is more what I would expect)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just realized you posted a comment. I currently created a brand channel. Using the title field, I add a brand name and use these titles in the Playa field. I then created a Playa field in the products group using the brand entries. Would it be better to create a category of brands and use seg2cat, so I can create categories from Segment_6. I have the products being filtered by category and by price. I'm trying to create a segment_6 for additional filtering (ie. brand). I want to be able to filter by type of product, price and brand.